# linq to sql geting data from 2 tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to get data from 2 table using Linq , that one table had FK to the second table but not necessary has data (table review could have for each review   comments (many)) what i'm trying to get is: in a single view get  all the reviews and if there are any comments display them related to the review Id 
trying to use join get me error in my view (model pass is wrong i tried each table model) this is my code :

```
     public ActionResult ttt()
    {
        var model = from rev in db.reviews
                    join com in db.Comments
                    on rev.ReviewId equals com.ReviewId into JoineRevCom
                    from com in JoineRevCom.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new
                    {
                        rev.ReviewBody,
                        rev.ReviewHeadLine,
                        Comments = com != null ? com.CommentBody : null
                    };
        return View(model);

    }
@model IEnumerable< SiteMvcPro.Models.Review>
```

Comment: Your `select new { ... }` is creating a collection of anonymous objects (not a collection of `Review` objects). You need to create a view model with the properties you want (e.g. `ReviewVM`) and use `select new ReviewVM { .... }` (and change the model in the view to `model IEnumerable<ReviewVM>`

Comment: Look at left outer join on following webpage : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b#content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always I would start by writing a view model for this view containing the information that I would like to display and never send anonymous objects to your view like you did in your code.

Let's suppose that you want to display a list of reviews and for each review the list of corresponding comments. So your view model might look something along those lines:

```
public class ReviewViewModel
{
    public int ReviewId { get; set; }
    public string ReviewBody { get; set; }
    public string ReviewHeadLine { get; set; }
    public IList<CommentViewModel> Comments { get; set; }
}

public class CommentViewModel
{
    public string CommentBody { get; set; }
}
```

with this defined you could perform your LINQ query to extract the necessary data and project to this view model:

```
IEnumerable<ReviewViewModel> viewModel = 
    from review in db.reviews
    join comment in db.Comments
    on review.ReviewId equals comment.ReviewId into joinedReviewComment
    select new ReviewViewModel // <-- Always project to a view model and never to an anonymous object
    {
        review.ReviewBody,
        review.ReviewHeadLine,
        Comments = joinedReviewComment.Select(c => new CommentViewModel
        {
            CommentBody = c.CommentBody,
        }).ToList(),
    };

return View(viewModel.ToList()); // <-- Always pass a view model to your view
```

And now all that's left is to display this information in your strongly typed view:

```
@model IList<ReviewViewModel>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Review id</th>
            <th>Review body</th>
            <th>Review headline</th>
            <th>Review comments</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].ReviewId)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].ReviewBody)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].ReviewHeadLine)</td>
                <td>
                    @for (var j = 0; j < Model[i].Comments.Count; j++)
                    {
                        <div>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].Comments[j].CommentBody)
                        </div>
                    }
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This being said projecting is one thing but filtering your data is another. Suppose that you have millions of reviews and each review has millions of comments. Making the aforementioned query will simply bring your server down pretty quickly. So think about that when designing your application and views. Don't hesitate to use the Where, Skip and Take operators to filter your result-sets down into a meaningful collection of data that is reasonable enough to be displayed on a single view.